# Pagin3 - Why LoadType.REFRESH is always called?

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-paging, android-paging-3

Recenlty i migrate my implementation of chat messages from Paging2 to Paging3. With the old implementation the initial messages are loaded from **DB** and if is empty then go to load the initial bunch of data from the netowkork with the function **onZeroItemsLoaded** and subsequently calls to **onItemAtEndLoaded** and **onItemAtFrontLoaded** more data is loaded and with Paging3 we use LoadType to replicate the same behaviour.

From debug i see that LoadType.REFRESH is called every time i enter to messages view refreshing my initial data in the **DB**, is that the expected behaviour? If so how can avoid that and only load the initial data if **DB** is empty?

**Note:** I know i can check for state of the **DB** and decide what to do but i looking for a Paging3 library solution.

Comment: Do you mean REFRESH in RemoteMediator or PagingSource? Refresh behavior for remote is controlled by result of what `RemoteMediator.initialize` returns. You can check there if your data is stake and if not, simple return `SKIP_INITIAL_REFRESH`